# Vertical motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, gravity, kinematics

Ball $A$ is thrown vertically upward from the top of a $30$ m high building with an initial velocity of $5$ m/s. At the same instant, another ball $B$ is thrown upward from the ground with an initial velocity of $20$ m/s. Determine the height from the ground and the time at which they pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtown's equations of motion with constant acceleration (Here, the acceleration is only due to gravity neglecting the air resistance). Try to solve for the the displacement (height) for each ball separately as a function in time. Once you get both displacements as functions in time, you can equate them and solve for the time and consequently, you can solve for the height where they pass each other.

- Remember, for ball A, it starts at an initial height that's different from the initial height of ball B, therefore, you must be consistent while you choose your coordinate system.